# Is it possible to avoid function names at all in Kotlin DSL?

Tags: kotlin, dsl, receiver

In [Kotlin DSL](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html) example they use `plus` signs to implement raw content inserting:

```
html {
    head {
        title {+"XML encoding with Kotlin"}
    }
    // ...
}
```

Is it possible to define "nameless" functions in receiver to be able to write

```
html {
    head {
        title {"XML encoding with Kotlin"}
    }
    // ...
}
```

Are there any plans to do so in future versions of Kotlin?

Is there such things in languages, other than Kotlin?

Answer (score 5):

I can think of two solutions to your problem:

1. Make the lambda with receiver return a `String`:

   ```
   fun title(init: Title.() -> String) {
       val t = Title().apply {
           children.add(TextElement(init()))
       }
       children.add(t)
   }
   ```

   You can now call the `title` as suggested in OP. Actually this seems to be overhead in this particular scenario though and I'd recommend the following.
2. Create another `title` method that takes a `String` directly:

   ```
   class Head : TagWithText("head") {
       fun title(init: Title.() -> Unit) = initTag(Title(), init)
       fun title(text: String) {
           val t = Title().apply {
               children.add(TextElement(text))
           }
           children.add(t)
       }
   }
   ```

   Used like this:

   ```
   head {
       title("XML encoding with Kotlin")
   }
   ```

Comment: I always kinda wondered why they didn't just do *that* in that example. No real need for re-defining the unary + operator.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, the `+` operator in the DSL example is overloaded for the purpose of appending multiple parts within the same block. If there's a single value that you want to handle in the DSL, there's indeed no need for such things as the overloaded operator. If you want to handle multiple values in a block, you need to pass  them all somewhere.

Comment: You could also make title infix, which would remove the need for the brackets

Comment: why is option 1 overhead?